# Significance testing between two set of SNPs

Tags: statistical-significance, variance, reml

After performing GWAS, I calculated the percentage of phenotypic variance (SNP-based heritability) for top SNPs and random SNPs using GREML (GCTA).
The variance of random SNPs was calculated for 3 different groups of randomly chosen SNPs and then averaged to get the final result.
Top SNPs explained much more variance than random ones (10% > 0.2%). I want to check if the difference is statistically significant.

Which significance test should I use for this?
Is t-test the right solution?

Comment: Yes. This is a nice way of testing it. Use a t-test.